# в чем ошибка в скрипте? python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Хочу спросить на счет данной ошибки, из за чего она возникает, его я ошибся или совсем что то не верно(что скорее всего).
Суть задачи скрипта = есть конфиг, в него надо вносить изменения пользователем через input. Нужно чтобы была проверка на параметры в которых только путь до папки, и только да\нет можно написать (+ еще скорее всего надо для параметров только с цифрами сделать проверку, но я пока незнаю как, если будет оказана помощь еще и в этом, буду очень благодарен). Дак вот я сделал функция на проверку имеется ли папка в системе, создал словарь со всеми параметрами и их значениями (если делать только для проверки папки, все работает хорошо, проблема именно в параметрами да\нет). Вот собственно говоря суть проблемы, спасибо заранее добрым людям которые помогут) Скриншот конфига и сам код скрипта приложены с посту.

[image: Как выглядит конфиг.файл]

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
path = '/home/artem/.synbak/rsync/test3.conf'
name1 = input('what setting you to change? ')
value1 = input('what you want to change in this setting: ')



def set_parametrs(name1, value1):
    with open(path) as f:
        current_config = f.read().splitlines()
    for i, option in enumerate(current_config):
        if option.split("=")[0].strip() == name1:
            current_config[i] = '%s = %s' % (name1, value1)
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(current_config))
        f.close()


def check_dir():
    if os.path.isdir(value1):
        print('we have this dir')
        return True
    else:
        print('we dont have this dir')
        return False


d = {
    'backup_destination_automake': ('yes', 'no'),
    'backup_destination_prefix': ('yes', 'no'),
    'backup_schedule': ('yes', 'no'),
    'backup_keep_on_errors': ('yes', 'no'),
    'method_rsync_sudo': ('yes', 'no'),
    'method_rsync_differential': ('yes', 'no'),
    'method_verify': ('yes', 'no'),
    'method_device_eject': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_remote_uri_down': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_stdout': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_stdout_on_errors': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_email': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_email_on_errors': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_email_rcpt': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_html': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_html_on_errors': ('yes', 'no'),
    'report_html_logo': ('yes', 'no'),
    'backup_source': check_dir,
    'backup_destination': check_dir,
    'backup_exclude': check_dir
}

'''param_dir = {
    'backup_source': check_dir,
    'backup_destination': check_dir,
    'backup_exclude': check_dir
}'''


def check_yes_no():
    for key, value in d.items():
        if name1 == key and value1 in d[key]:
            print('this parametr is valid')
        return True
    else:
        print('this parametr is invalid')
    return False


if name1 and value1 and d[name1]():
    set_parametrs(name1, value1)
elif check_yes_no:
    set_parametrs(name1, value1)
else:
        print("bad")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в функции `check_yes_no()`. Если `name1 == key and value1 in d[key]` то у вас только выводится сообщения, а функция возвращает `True` вне зависимости от выполнения условия, то есть на первой же итерации.

```
def check_yes_no():
    for key, value in d.items():
        if name1 == key and value1 in d[key]:
            print('this parametr is valid')
            return True
    else:
        print('this parametr is invalid')
    return False
```

Для параметров которые равны одному числу (типо `backup_keep`) используйте [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric). Для проверки параметров которые равны набору чисел или диапазону используйте [регулярные выражения](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/).

Comment: d[key] я тоже ставил, в итоге ошибка вида if name1 and value1 and d[name1]():
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: почему то во время выполнения скрипт работает только в той частью словаря которая с check_dir, то что касается да\нет = вылетает ошибка. Я честно признаться не знаю почему)

Comment: @ArtemMazur зачем () после d[name1]? Python думает что d[name1] это функция и пытается вызвать ее, отсюда и ошибка TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.

Comment: да спасибо, и правда что то не заметил как поставил. Но новая проблема в том, что независимо от того что я пишу для например report_html (yes или ttttrtgegerg), скрипт все равно сохраняет то значение которое я ввожу, а по задумке должен позволять сохранять только yes\no, в противном случае выводить ошибку, и также функция check_dir перестала работать для тех параметров где обязателен путь. P.s спасибо что помогаете)

Comment: частично проблему я решил, если это можно так сказать. (добавил к d[name1] == check_dir() и к elif check_yes_no() ). У меня есть к Вам просьба помочь сделать так чтобы при изменении параметра например report_html на yes, скрипт не писал одновременно 'we dont have this dir' и this parametr is valid. То есть чтобы при изменении параметра с yes\no он использовал функцию только check_yes_no, и не использовал check_dir